# OAuth2 implementation using JWK/JWS/JWE/JWT

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt, bearer-token

I need to setup an environment where the client, resource owner server and authorization server communicate with each other using the standard OAuth2 APIs.

These are my requirements:

1. Usage of OAuth2 framework.
2. No TLS connections between client, resource owner and authorization server.
3. Usage of JWK/JWS/JWE/JWT technologies for security.
4. Ability to scale to large number of clients.

Is there a good strategy/open source projects available which already support this workflow?

If I need to write my own workflow, is there a good starting point?

Comment: Why no TLS? This conflict with the ability to scale to a large number of clients.

Comment: @MvdD - The reason I am not really keen on using TLS is because the clients could be really light-weight and might not have the required libraries to support HTTPS.

Comment: You'll find it's impossible to protect against eavesdroppers and man-in-the-middle attacks without transport security.

Comment: OAuth2 without TLS ise useless - then better do not offer login at all. If using TLS is really a no-go, stick to OAUTH1.0a which has security features like signatures etc inbuilt.

Comment: Did you check Keycloak already?